# Angularjs remove table row with different background color in odd even selected row

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table with different background color in odd even row, also there is different background color for selected row. A button to remove the object in array that bind with the table data.

The problem is when I remove the first row of the table or array, the new first row background color(which is selected) did not change to selected background color (I think it remain the previous css class). But when I remove other row, nothing went wrong, the new selected row has background color as intended.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("aCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.arr_obj = [{
      "num": 1,
      "title": "abc",
    },

    {
      "num": 2,
      "title": "def"
    },

    {
      "num": 3,
      "title": "ghi"
    },

    {
      "num": 4,
      "title": "lmn"
    },

    {
      "num": 5,
      "title": "opq"
    }

  ];

  $scope.selectedId = 0;

  $scope.setindex = function(id) {
    $scope.selectedId = id;

  }

  $scope.remove_click = function() {
    if ($scope.arr_obj.length >= 1) {
      $scope.arr_obj.splice($scope.selectedId, 1);
      if ($scope.arr_obj.length >= 1) {
        if ($scope.selectedId >= 1) {
          $scope.selectedId = $scope.selectedId - 1;
        } else {
          $scope.selectedId = 0;
        }
        console.log($scope.selectedId);
      }
    }
  }


  $scope.ClassOdd = function(id) {
    if (id === $scope.selectedId)
      return "selected";
    else
      return "odd";
  };

  $scope.ClassEven = function(id) {
    if (id === $scope.selectedId)
      return "selected";
    else
      return "even";

  };
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.selected {
  background-color: pink;
}
.odd {
  background-color: green;
}
.even {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="aCtrl" class="main">

  <div>
    <table>

      <tr>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>checkbox</th>
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="row in arr_obj" ng-click="setindex($index)" ng-class-odd="ClassOdd($index)" ng-class-even="ClassEven($index)">
        <td>{{row.num}}</td>
        <td>{{row.title}}</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>

  <input type="button" value="Remove" ng-click="remove_click($index)">
  <p>current selectedId = {{selectedId}}
    <p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jx8ztcum/

May I know how this happens? Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *solve* this by adding the `track by` expression to your `ng-repeat`.

**Why *track by***

`track by` is used to link your data with the DOM made by `ng-repeat`- this could be useful for paging, filtering, adding/removing from the `ng-repeat` list.

(without `track by` angular links the DOM with the collection by injecting  a `$$hashKey` property into the `ng-repeat` collection, and will regenerate it with any change in the collection)

See demo below and [`Updated fiddle here`](https://jsfiddle.net/udpu3ajo/):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("aCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.arr_obj = [{"title": "abc"},{"title": "def"},{"title": "ghi"},{"title": "lmn"},{"title": "opq"}];

  $scope.selectedId = 0;

  $scope.setindex = function(id) {
    $scope.selectedId = id;
  }

  $scope.remove_click = function() {
    if ($scope.arr_obj.length >= 1) {
      $scope.arr_obj.splice($scope.selectedId, 1);
      if ($scope.arr_obj.length >= 1) {
        if ($scope.selectedId >= 1) {
          $scope.selectedId = $scope.selectedId - 1;
        } else {
          $scope.selectedId = 0;
        }
        console.log($scope.selectedId);
      }
    }
  }


  $scope.ClassOdd = function(id) {
    if (id === $scope.selectedId)
      return "selected";
    else
      return "odd";
  };

  $scope.ClassEven = function(id) {
    if (id === $scope.selectedId)
      return "selected";
    else
      return "even";
  };
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.selected {
  background-color: pink;
}
.odd {
  background-color: green;
}
.even {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="aCtrl" class="main">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>num</th>
        <th>title</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in arr_obj track by $index" ng-click="setindex($index)" ng-class-odd="ClassOdd($index)" ng-class-even="ClassEven($index)">
        <td>{{$index}}</td>
        <td>{{row.title}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Remove" ng-click="remove_click($index)">
  <p>current selectedId = {{selectedId}}<p>
</div>
```